# About the drupal hook_theme_registry_alter

Tags: hooks

I have a query:--

I have installed a module [imgix](https://www.drupal.org/project/imgix) which implements like this:--

It implements hook_theme_registry_alter;

```
function imgix_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  // Overrides theme_image().

   unset($theme_registry['image']['preprocess functions']);

   if (isset($theme_registry['image'])) {
       $theme_registry['image']['function'] = 'imgix_theme_image';
       $theme_registry['image']['theme path'] = drupal_get_path('module','imgix');
       $path_module = drupal_get_path('module','imgix');
       $theme_registry['image']['file'] = 'imgix.module';
       $theme_registry['image']['includes'] = array($path_module."/imgix.inc");
  }


 return $theme_registry;
}
```

I have now installed a new module called [lazyloader](https://www.drupal.org/project/lazyloader).

which is also using same hook and overriding the image tag.

How can I call both of the function one after the another from different modules and overriding the same image theme.( I have tried. I changed the weight of module .The module having higher weight executed successfully. and the other one does not.)

So How to solve the above problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This will never work as the later hook just overrides the previous.
You can implement your own module, with `hook_theme_registry_alter` and point `$theme_registry['image']['function']`  to your custom theme function.

Then you will need to re-implement `imgix_theme_image` and `lazyloader_image` (they are very similar and doing the same: assigning attributes to img tag) in your custom theme function.

This is a basic explanation, you will probably need to take care of other `$theme_registry['image']` parameters to get it to work.